# Subquery slows performance on query

Tags: sql, join, subquery, inner-join

I have a query there are two sections in it "Searching section 1" and "Searching section 2" when both sections are uncomment query takes upto 23 seconds just for 87 records. If I comment one section (Section 1 is comented right now) It gives result in 2 seconds.
How can I imporve the performance of query with both sections uncommented?

```
   declare @CountryId bigint = 336,
 @Lat varchar(30) = '31.512594000000004',
 @Lng varchar(30) = '74.34114',
 @Distance int = 10,
 @SearchString varchar(30) = 'sprite'
 DECLARE @orig_lat DECIMAL(12, 9) = CAST(@Lat AS DECIMAL(12,9));
 DECLARE @orig_lng DECIMAL(12, 9) = CAST(@Lng AS DECIMAL(12,9));
 DECLARE @orig geography = geography::Point(@orig_lat, @orig_lng, 4326);

 select main.* from 
 ChowDeal.UVW_CD_SearchDeals search inner join 
 ChowDeal.UVW_CD_DealMenusForCustomer main 
 on search.Latitude is not null
    and search.Longitude is not null    
    and @orig.STDistance(geography::Point(search.Latitude, search.Longitude, 4326)) / 1609.34 < @Distance
    and main.MasterMenuID = search.MasterMenuID
 where 
    (


    -- Searching section 1
        --(@SearchString = '' or search.MenuName like '%'+ @SearchString +'%' )
        --or
        --(@SearchString = '' or search.Ingredient like '%'+ @SearchString +'%'  )
        --or
        --(@SearchString = '' or search.RestaurantName like '%'+ @SearchString +'%'  )

    -- Searching section 2
        --or
         search.MasterMenuID in 
                                        (   select DealID from ChowDeal.UVW_CD_SearchDeals 
                                            where MenuName like '%'+ @SearchString +'%' and DealID > 0                                          
                                        ) 
        )
```

Comment: I don't know if this would help, but the three @ SearchString = '' seem redundant, can't you put the three searches together and only have one @ SearchString = ''? Do you have indexes on any of these columns you are searching on? That might help

Comment: To help you we need more information regarding table schema, indexes, execution plan etc.

Comment: @Kelly Yes I have indexes on all columns

Comment: why are you joining on is not null condition instead of it being in there where clause? Same with the aggregate function- it seems youre having the system do unnecessary work in the join. Also, what database management system is this?

Comment: To get data from specific radius and to less number of records I applied joins. this shrinks records from 4000 to 800. But filtering from 800 also takes 30 sec when both sections are uncomment.

Comment: I have concated MenuName, Ingredient, ResturantName, this brings it to 7 seconds but it's stil slow.